# Not able to create google credential for app engine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api

I am trying to create application default credentials for my app engine project for accessing google APIs. I am developing in eclipse IDE and I have defined the environment variable:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the json key file downloaded to my computer. But, I am gettin following exception:

> java.io.IOException: Application Default Credentials failed to create
>   the Google App Engine service account credentials class
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.
>   Check that the component 'google-api-client-appengine' is deployed.

**Stacktrace:**

> Application Default Credentials failed to create the Google App Engine
>   service account credentials class
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.
>   Check that the component 'google-api-client-appengine' is deployed.
>   java.io.IOException: Application Default Credentials failed to create
>   the Google App Engine service account credentials class
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.
>   Check that the component 'google-api-client-appengine' is deployed.
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.tryGetAppEngineCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:282)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:161)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:88)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)

Comment: Hi, could you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 14):

You may be missing one or more of the required dependencies. Here's what I am including with a working app that uses AppIdentity from the development server:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Worked for me, when in addition to running 'gcloud auth application-default login' in terminal.

Comment: saved my day! Thanks, Adam!